# Where is a good place to start with (hidden) state-space models?

Tags: time-series, bayesian, references, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I'm interested in (hidden) state-space models. My language here might be poorly articulated as I'm quite new to this area of math. The topic of Kalman filters has come "across my desk" a number of times over the last few months and I'm not sure if this is the ideal model to jump into state-space models. Though, I would like to get to this point. My questions are:

- If not Kalman filters, where should I start?
- I primarily use Bayesian methods in my work, is this relevant?
- What are some core ideas behind state space models that will help guide my self-study?
- I'm familiar with latent variable modeling, but haven't used it much in the time-series capacity; is this problematic?

Edit: This [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfdBiKsT0ks) was pretty helpful. It introduced the random walk state space model, suggesting that it was the de facto place to start. Further, the lecturer discussed that each observation, $Y[i]$, was independent of each other, however, each hidden state, $X[i]$ are conditionally independent of each other (past and future), with the exception of and conditioned on $X[i-1]$.

The lecturer showed that the random walk model does pretty well when data is complete, however, its credible intervals explode when the model runs out of observations (the successive errors are additive.)

And so this introduces the idea of Dynamic Linear Models, where you essentially keep the random walk model but add in variables and regression coefficients. And so even if you run out of observed $Y$ values, if you have some input variable, the credible intervals will be better constrained than the random walk model.

I haven't dug into Kalman Filters yet, but it would seem that other state-space models improve upon the random walk model by managing the input variables and their corresponding relationships with inferred parameters.

Hopefully I'm on the right track!

Comment: This is a very general questin, maybe to broad, it could benefit from mentioning your use case(s). But see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294559/hidden-markov-model-with-multiple-factors

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Ecology and epidemiology, primarily population dynamics. I'd like to start with the fundamentals and build up rather than jump into something opaque without the proper background context.